# Github - how to add several discoverable licenses?

Tags: github

I could not find answer by googling. I want to add several free licenses for them to be easily seen on project page.

https://github.blog/changelog/2022-05-26-easily-discover-and-navigate-to-multiple-licenses-in-repositories/
seems to suggest a project can have at least two licenses as its "property".

https://docs.github.com/en/communities/setting-up-your-project-for-healthy-contributions/adding-a-license-to-a-repository

> Add a file named LICENSE(.md)

I can imagine I will add `LICENSE` and then `LICENSE.md` and it will add two to my project. Is it really the way? And two is max?

I can have `LICENSE` file mentioning as many as I want, but I want my project to be better visible via Github search. Is it worth the effort, BTW? TIA

Comment: The first link suggests suffixes: `LICENSE-BSD`, `LICENSE-GPL`, `LICENSE-MIT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but from what I gather you should be able to add a `LICENSE-XXX(.md)` where `XXX` is the abbreviation of the license type you want, so `LICENSE-MIT`, `LICENSE-GPL`. Each file will be detected as a licensen.

Comment: Thanks. "Almost". Cannot be sure how to add e.g. both GPL-2 and GPL-3. I see I can change end of the file after `LICENSE-GPL.` but after I added such file created from template I do not see this license in `about` of the project.

Comment: I've found a way. "Valid" file name `LICENSE-` then any letters and dot, no digits.  after `LICENSE-GPL` digits result in non discoverability, but letters are ok, so one can name file e.g. `LICENSE-GPLa.md` or `LICENSE-GPLtwo.md`. I was able to see several added in the `about`, thanks! P.S.